# Google Calendar API Returning (503) Backend Error

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

Receiving `(503) Backend Error` from Google when using their PHP API package `"google/apiclient": "1.1.4"`

- Quota is all good (using 3000/1,000,000 calls)
- API calls were previously working this morning.

Any thoughts on why Google would be responding with this? I though it may have been related to the Exponential Backoff algorithm they make use of but we've halted calls to the API for a good hour and then some now and still getting that same error.

---

**Update**: I just noticed while toggling between the calendars we want to read that a calendar called 'Birthdays' was breaking things when we tried to read it.

Not sure why Google returns a 503 on this Birthdays calendar specifically but it's resolved for now. Does anyone have any insight into why a Birthday's Calendar would return a `503 backendError` from Google?

Also found this Google Thread for the same error.. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/j9opJS9ZzCg

Comment: Isn't 503 more of an error on their end, like a server error? Maybe some weird downtime happening on their servers?

Comment: @georaldc That's what I was thinking, however their server status page shows all green.

Comment: send the request again it should work.  I like to call 503 a server hiccup.

Comment: 503 Service Unavailable 
The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.
For all errors that are time based especially the 503 status code errors, we recommend your code catch the exception. Try to read this Official Google Document: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/limits